# Redis XRANGE: ERR Invalid stream ID specified as stream command argument

Tags: redis

I'm trying to iterate through a Redis stream using `XRANGE`. The [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro) states that I need to prefix `(` to my last timestamp to be exclusive. Quoting the documentation:

> In order to continue the iteration with the next two items, I have to pick the last ID returned, that is 1519073279157-0 and add the prefix ( to it. The resulting exclusive range interval, that is (1519073279157-0 in this case, can now be used as the new start argument for the next XRANGE call:

But if I do that I get an error, below are two commands, one without the exclusive prefix and one with which generates an error:

```
redis:6379> XRANGE unittest 1612384862718-0 +
1) 1) "1612384862718-0"
   2) 1) "x"
      2) "42"
2) 1) "1612384862780-0"
   2) 1) "x"
      2) "43"
3) 1) "1612384862888-0"
   2) 1) "x"
      2) "44"
redis:6379> XRANGE unittest (1612384862718-0 +
(error) ERR Invalid stream ID specified as stream command argument
```

The example in the Redis documentation looks the same to me:

```
> XRANGE mystream (1519073279157-0 + COUNT 2
1) 1) 1519073280281-0
   2) 1) "foo"
      2) "value_3"
2) 1) 1519073281432-0
   2) 1) "foo"
      2) "value_4"
```

`redis_version:6.0.6`

Comment: Exclusive stream query intervals were/will only (be) added in Redis 6.2 (author of that specific feature here ;))

Comment: Ah, so how do I achieve it <6.2? Just increment the counter after `-`? By the way, you can post that as an answer, that certainly answers my question.

Comment: Sure, done. Also, what programming language/client are you using. Some should have the logic in my answer abstracted anyway.

Comment: I was testing with just the command line, but in general Python, I just wanted to keep the question as focused as possible, so I also abstracted to the Redis CLI.

Comment: Gotcha - regrettably the current redis-py version doesn't feature the abovementioned convenience abstraction :/ something for the roadmap

Comment: I think it will work actually. I looked at the code briefly, it looks like `redis-py` is just appending the timestamp passed to it onto a redis query string, so I can modify the timestamp string and pass it to `redis-py` with `(` and it will pass through to redis unchecked. I'll test it out with 6.2RC3 soon and post back if it doesn't work. `redis-py` just lacks a property to specify exclusive.

Comment: Oh, yeah, totally doable, I was expressing my chagrin that the redis-py client doesn't handle this transparently yet :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for exclusive/open range query intervals was/will be added in Redis 6.2 - see https://github.com/redis/redis/pull/8072.

For previous versions, the recommended approach is to have the client code to:

1. After calling the first XRANGE/XREVRANGE, take the last ID
2. Parse the last ID for timestamp and sequence (both 64-bit integers)
3. If doing XRANGE, try to increment the sequence. For XREVRANGE decrement it.
4. If the sequence overflows/underflows, perform the same arithmetic on the timestamp and init the sequence (MAXINT for XREVRANGE, 0 for XRANGE)
5. Handle the "0-0" and "MAXINT-MAXJNT" cases
6. Use the new ID in the next call to the query and repeat